# Angular ui-router user authentication check

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a very simple authentication control using ui-router. I do the checking in the backend, though, I want to redirect users if they aren't logged in.

However, when I try to visit /profile, nothing happens. If I console.log() a text like "yes", it's being logged out unlimited amount of time until I get stack size exceeded error. It keeps hitting /authcheck url, I can see that via network tools of Chrome.

If I remove `$state.go(toState.name)`, I see a blank page and `console.log()` shows that user is signed in (which I am), but then I can't see `/profile` page, as expected.

What could be the problem here?

`/authcheck` returns `200` or `403`.

my factory

```
angular.module('site.profile').factory('Profile', ["$http", function($http) {
  return {
    authCheck: function() {
      return $http.get('/authcheck');
    }
  };
}]);
```

ui-router

```
angular.module('site.profile.routes')
.run(
  ['$rootScope', 'Profile', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($rootScope, Profile, $state, $stateParams) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.name !== 'auth') {
          event.preventDefault();
          Profile.authCheck().then(function(returned) {
            if (returned.status === 200) {
              console.log("yes!");
              console.log(toState.name);
              //$state.go($state);
            } else {
              $state.go('auth');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  ]
)


.config(
  ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });

      $stateProvider
        .state('profile', {
          url: '/profile',
          views: {
            '': {
              templateUrl: 'views/profile/profile.html'
            },
            'post@profile': {
              templateUrl: 'views/post.html'
            },
            'nav@profile': {
              templateUrl: 'views/shared/nav/nav.html'
            },
            'top@profile': {
              templateUrl: 'views/profile/top.html'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('auth', {
          url: '/signin',
          template: "please sign in"
        });
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing the default for every state change except `auth`.

You need a way to store user once they have been authorized so you don't need to make a new request each time and then you can check if that user object exists before preventing the change

I personally prefer using a `resolve` in a top level parent state so the authorization only needs to be checked once on the parent. Then all child states will be blocked until that parent is resolved